# Items in the scroller appear in front of elements preceding the wrapper

Tags: iscroll

I have a typical iscroll 5 markup:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul class="scroller">
      <li>foo</li>
      ...
   </ul>
</div>

new Scroll(document.getElementById('wrapper'));
```

The wrapper has an **absolute** position. The scroller has a **relative** position.

The issue is that, as I scroll down, the list items show **in front of** my h1 "Hello" element.

I supposed that I could fix this by explicitly set z-indexes, but I would like to avoid doing that. I assume that it has something to do with my wrapper absolute position.

What would be the cleanest way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the css of your wrapper to overflow: hidden to prevent anything that overflows the container from being visible.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

What is happening is that once you set an item as position: absolute, it's placed on top of all the other elements in its context, so in this case it's placed on top of the H1.